# Use an Access Web Database as a data source for Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, powerpivot, microsoft-access

I have an Access 2010 Web Database published to SharePoint as described here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/build-an-access-database-to-share-on-the-web-HA010356866.aspx

If my Access database were named "projects", after it's published to SharePoint it can be accessed via a URL that looks like:
`http://<servername>/projects/`

There is no "filename" for the published Access database that I know of.

So, if I want to use the published Access databse as a data source in Excel (PowerPivot, etc.) or in SSRS, is that possible?  What does the connection information look like in that case?  PowerPivot's Table Import Wizard will not accept something like `http://<servername>/projects/` as a valid Access database file name.